# How to tell IDE that variable is an object of a class?

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm (community ed) and there is a nice dropdown menu to view e.g. object methods.

[image]

I would like to always be able to see this info. However, this dropdown info is only visible for me if I'm in the same module as where my object was created. Is there a way to access it from other modules too, where I import the object as a function argument?

Comment: In general, it should work everywhere. Could you please provide a project structure & code example?